# Why does '' (empty string) permeate all strings?

Tags: javascript, string, standards, language-lawyer, ecma262

I just ran into a bit of confusion today, `"string".indexOf('');` always returns `0`, but I would expect `-1` (for `false`); inversely, `"string".lastIndexOf('');` always returns `6`

`lastIndexOf` is easier to understand, since string is 6 letters long (`"string".length`, being zero-indexed returns `5`) but I don't see anywhere in the ECMAscript spec ([5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.7) or [6.0](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.indexof)) that describes *why* `''` would be treated like a word/character boundary

What, exactly, is going on here?

Comment: Yes, `''` is treated like a word/character boundary.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns the _first_ occurrence of a found match and returns `-1` _only_ if the string isn't found at all.

Comment: `''` is treated like...ummm...an empty string. The first occurrence of an empty string inside another string is right at its start.

Comment: The "duplicate" is about Java. And this question asks for a clarification of the spec, not for a vague reason. So I vote to reopen and add [language-lawyer] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec says:

> Return the smallest possible integer *k* not smaller than *start* such
>   that *k*+*searchLen* is not greater than *len*, and for all
>   nonnegative integers *j* less than *searchLen*, the character at
>   position *k*+*j* of *S* is the same as the character at position *j*
>   of *searchStr*; but if there is no such integer *k*, then return the
>   value -1.

That condition is fulfilled at position 0 because of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth): since you are searching the empty string, any statement you can think of will hold for every character, because it has no characters.

More formally, for any statement `P`, if `S = ∅`, `P(x)` holds `∀ x ∈ S`.